# table updates automatically when another table updates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is called records and another is called calculation. I want to count the amount in records by two constraints(user_id and symbol), and show the result in calculation table.I try the following:

```
UPDATE calculation c
JOIN 
(
    SELECT user_id, symbol, sum(amount) as sum_amount
    FROM records
    GROUP BY user_id, symbol
) r ON r.user_id = c.user_id AND r.symbol = c.symbol
SET c.sumOfAmount = r.sum_amount
```

however, when I add a new record in the record table, the value in calculation table doesn't update. How can I make it to update each time when i make changes to the records table?

Comment: Does calculation have to be a table? Or would a View be a better option here?

Comment: since i want to do many calculations not only sum of amount, i want to make an api for calculation table so I only need to call one api and get a array of value. In the earlier stage i only have one table and try to make each calculation as an api, but found that it needs so many apis . so I decide to store the calculated values in another table